# How to check when all data from csv has been inserted to postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, async-await

I am using nodejs to parse csv file and insert the records into postgresql database. I want to check when all my records has been inserted and return success, so that i can call another function .Below is my code which i am trying

```
import * as pg from 'pg';
const { Pool } = pg.default;
import { parse } from "fast-csv";
import { testres1 } from './createpdf.js'
const testres = async () => {

      var pool = new Pool({
            connectionString: conString,
            idleTimeoutMillis: 0,
            connectionTimeoutMillis: 0,
            ssl: {
                rejectUnauthorized: false,
            },
        });

const query = "INSERT INTO _staging(firstName, lastName, Employee_ID, Employee_Unique_ID) \
            VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING Employee_ID";
        await pool.connect((err, client, done) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            try {
                csvData.shift();
                csvData.forEach(async row => {
                    await client.query(query, row, (err, res) => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err.stack + "error row:", row);
                        } else {
                            // console.log("inserted " + res.rowCount + " row:", row);
                            countrec = countrec + res.rowCount
                            console.log(csvData.length - 1)
                            console.log(countrec)
                            if (csvData.length === countrec) {
                                return 'finished !!!!!'
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
            } finally {
                done();
            }
        });

}

const ddd = await testres();
console.log('test :', ddd); /// here it is coming as undefined. Not getting 'finished !!!!!' in the return
const eee = await testres1();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) instead of callbacks as it makes maintaining the code easier. `node-postgres` also supports that and there is also an [example that you could refer](https://node-postgres.com/features/pooling).

In your case, one of the ways to achieve the desired result can be achieved by:

1. Connect to the pool

```js
const pool = new Pool({
  connectionString: conString,
  idleTimeoutMillis: 0,
  connectionTimeoutMillis: 0,
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  },
});

// the pool will emit an error on behalf of any idle clients
// it contains if a backend error or network partition happens
pool.on('error', (err, client) => {
  console.error('Unexpected error on idle client', err)
  // Add error handling
})

const client = await pool.connect()

const query = "INSERT INTO _staging(firstName, lastName, Employee_ID, Employee_Unique_ID) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING Employee_ID";
```

2. Once the connection is established, parse the CSV and insert data.

- Option 1: All the insertion can be done in parallel by using [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to have better performance.

```js
const queryPrommises = [];

csvData.shift();

// Prepare insert queries
csvData.forEach(row => queryPrommises.push(client.query(query, row)));

try {
  // Execute queries
  const result = await Promise.all(queryPrommises);
  
  // Check the result length with CSV length (-1 to ignore the header row)
  if(result.length === csvData.length - 1) {
    return 'finished !!!!!'
  } else {
    return 'Count does not match';
  }
} catch(err) {
  // At least one of the queries failed.
  console.log(err)
}
```

- Option 2: Insert the data one by one. We cannot use `forEach` here as we are doing asynchronous operations. Instead we need to use `for ... of` ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787/4350275)).

```js
csvData.shift();

let rowCount = 0;

// Insert the data one row at a time
for (const row of csvData) {
  try {
    await client.query(query, row);
    rowCount++;
  } catch(err) {
    // Row insertion failed. Handle the error
    console.log(err)
  }
}

// Check the count with CSV length (-1 to ignore the header row)
if(rowCount === csvData.length - 1) {
  return 'finished !!!!!'
} else {
  return 'Count does not match';
}
```

Comment: Fore even better performance, you can use [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) if you use [node-pg-copy-streams](https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-copy-streams).